# I have a string that can contains a lot of html tags. How can I get separately each tag with the content from a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, transformation

From the API I am receiving a string that contains html tags. How can I extract them from a string and put them into DOM to show on the page as a separate input? For example Title input for h2, content for paragraph etc
Example of the string:

```
description: '<b>First option</b><p>Equals</p><h2>22</h2>'
```

That string can contain the following tags: div, p, h1, h2, b

Thanks!

Comment: `body.InnerHTML = description;`. Or use another HTMLElement.

Comment: Sorry I Changed a bit my question to clarify that it's not for showing as a content but divide each tag values to separate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could firstly *match* the elements from the string, then use e.g. `html-react-parser` library to transform the separated *strings* into `JSX` elements.

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

export default function App() {
  const tags = str.match(
    /(<h[12]>.*?<\/h[12]>|<[bp]>.*?<\/[bp]>|<div>.*?<\/div>)/g,
  );

  const elements = tags.map((tag) => parse(tag));

  return <div className="App">{elements}</div>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-pond-dm70v8?file=/src/App.js

```js
const str = '<b>First option</b><p>Equals</p><h2>22</h2><div>ble</div>';

const tags = str.match(
  /(<h[12]>.*?<\/h[12]>|<[bp]>.*?<\/[bp]>|<div>.*?<\/div>)/g,
);

console.log(tags);
```